# Java Easy Subtraction

Tags: java, math

I've been having some trouble with a little math i've been doing in Java. Long story short, when I do:

```
double totalS = 1146.35;
double down = 114.63;

result = totalS - down;
```

And the result for this comes out as 1031.7199999999998, when doing this easy equation on a calculator produces 1031.72. Any idea?

Comment: Also see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: You can't program without knowing something about how floating point numbers work.

Comment: Well that's how primitive floating points work. You may try [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: You can round to two decimal places using Math.round